# Determine latest row added when no index is present

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve the most recently added customer. I don't have any column which stores the date/time the row was added, and my primary key is `Cust_ID`, which is not an `IDENTITY` column and is not necessarily entered in ascending order.

This is my table, `Customer`, and imagine three rows have been added in this order:

```
Cust_ID       Cust_Name      Cust_Age
-------------------------------------
2             C              23
6             A              25
3             B              22
```

in above example I want to get last record (`B`). Is there any predefined function in SQL Server which will return the last row of a table (without relying on ascending order)?

Comment: Why don't you just add a timestamp?

Comment: Isn't there a `Last(  )` method in sql

Comment: Is your CustID is identity element?

Comment: Cant you make your table as @davek suggest?

Comment: Well I suppose if you don't apply any order, it will be the last record if you loop on all of the records. But adding a timestamp or a unique identifier (with identity specifiction) field would be much more quick and easy

Comment: @Bartdude no, if you don't apply any order, a loop will run in an undetermined order. SQL Server will choose whatever order is most efficient. Why do you think that means the last inserted row will end up last?

Comment: @ALL is there any predefined function in sql server which will return last row of a table(without ascending).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand > It seemed logic to me :-) Apparently not. But if you run 5 times the same (non-ordered) query on that table, I presume the order will always be the same no ? So there must be some kind of order somewhere. Now I must say I'm just guessing here :-) Now this kind of design will cause other troubles so better change the schema anyway

Comment: @Bartdude Nope. Add/remove an index, apply a service pack, flush the procedure cache, update statistics, restart the server, add a trace flag, change a server option, etc. etc. - all of things can make it change.

Comment: @Aaron > OK thanks for this. I know have an answer to a question I never asked myself before, but it could be of use if I ever encounter such a bad database design :-)

Comment: The flagged duplicate is a question about when a table has an identity column, and this question is not.  This question should be re-opened, and Aaron's answer should be marked as the correct answer, so that this question can be used to flag future duplicates.

Answer (score 15):

No, there is no predefined function in SQL Server which will return the "last row" of a table.

By definition, a table is an unordered set of rows. Imagine you throw a bunch of marbles in a bag. Now open the bag and ask someone else which marble went in first or last. Now throw them all on the floor, and when someone else comes in the room, ask them which hit the floor first or last. You can't do it, because there is no additional information that indicates anything about the order in which they fell.

The same is true for a table in SQL Server. Unless you add an IDENTITY column, or a datetime column, or a trigger, or use external functionality like change tracking, CDC, auditing, etc., there is no way for SQL Server to tell you which row was inserted last. You may *think* that just selecting from the table without an order by clause *looks* like it is returning data in the right order, this is pure coincidence. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.floobat
(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  n VARCHAR(16), 
  x CHAR(4000) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);

INSERT dbo.floobat(ID,n) VALUES(1,'Sparky');
INSERT dbo.floobat(ID,n) VALUES(2,'Aaron');
INSERT dbo.floobat(ID,n) VALUES(3,'Norbert'); -- <-- inserted last

SELECT ID, n FROM dbo.floobat;
```

Ok, so by default, this seems to be okay. Results:

```
ID    n
--    -------
1     Sparky
2     Aaron
3     Norbert -- < yes, this is right
```

However, let's make a change to the table that your application or whatever else relies on the above ordering will have no idea about:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.floobat(n);

SELECT ID, n FROM dbo.floobat;
```

Uh oh! Results:

```
ID    n
--    -------
2     Aaron
3     Norbert
1     Sparky -- < oops, this is no longer right
```

You have to remember this: if you don't include an ORDER BY clause, you are *telling* SQL Server that you don't care about order. So it is going to find the most efficient way to return the data, and that could lead to different observed ordering. Adding the index above gave SQL Server a better access path to retrieving the data. It still used a scan, but that index was way skinnier than the clustered index (which could only fit two rows on a page).

Even without the index, you probably wouldn't get the results you expect, since it is convoluted by the fact that your `Cust_ID` column is not being inserted in ascending order. So if you insert `5` and than `2`, selecting without an ORDER BY will actually result in `2` then `5` (assuming no better index exists).

Other things other than creating (or dropping, or changing, or rebuilding) an index can cause the same sort of change in ordering behavior. Apply a service pack, CU or hotfix; flushing the procedure cache; using various RECOMPILE options; updating statistics; restarting the server; adding or disabling a trace flag; changing a server option options; moving the database to a different server; etc. etc.

So, if you want to track this information, you'll need to add it yourself in some way, as several of the other answers have addressed.

Comment: HI @Aron Bertrand Thanx alot for above description about a table. you completed solve my concept about this problem.

Comment: great explanation 1 vote up

Answer (score 3):

You can not get the Last Row Inserted untill unless you have either `IDENTITY` or `DateTime` Column  in your Table.

Answer (score 3):

If you have no metadata available in your table, and you can't edit your schema to afford either a timestamp or an identity column, then you should rely on SQL Server's metadata generation mechanisms. One is [CDC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

CDC stands for [change data capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture), and as the name denotes, it's there to help you understand any change that has been applied to data. I think you can use this metadata, to understand what is the latest record that has been inserted into a table.

Answer (score 2):

either

- add a timestamp

or

- add an autoincrement/identity key

Comment: @devek is there any predefined function in sql server which will return last row of a table(without ascending).

Answer (score 2):

If you cant change your table schema then you may consider adding a new table with same schema that store only the last record inserted,